# Lists of Figures and Tables is not generated: error

Tags: table-of-contents, errors

Finishing my twosided article, I want to generate the LOF and LOT.

The following error occurs over and over for a lot of figures (the first being: "Undefined control sequence" and the second being: "Missing number treated as zero":

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\l@figure #1#2->\ifnum \c@lofdepth 
                                   >\z@ \vskip \cftbeforefigskip {\leftskip ...
l.10 ...DPJIP2009}\relax }}{11}{figure.caption.14}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   >
l.10 ...DPJIP2009}\relax }}{11}{figure.caption.14}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

I use PDFLATEX via texstudio (MAC OSX) and \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}. I also just updated all packages, no difference (did not reboot computer).

I hope someone can help.

Comment: Please show the exact full error message, the undefined control sequence message for example shows which command was undefined.

Comment: I updated the error code. I hope this is what you ask for.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard classes have a `tocdepth` counter but do not a `lofdepth` counter (the internal name of which would be `\c@lofdepth`) so most likely you at one point used a package for extended list of figures handling and that package is no longer loaded leaving the temporary files in an inconsistent state.

Delete the `.lof` `.toc` `.lot` and `.aux` files and re-latex and things should get back in sync.

Comment: Your answer helped me to fix it. In the preamble I had: \usepackage[titles,figures]{tocloft}. I do not know why 'figures' was in there (as a starter you sometimes just copy codes). Deleting it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Joost mentioned in a comment, this can happen when using a specific option for the `tocloft` package.

In my case, I had the following code in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
```

The `subfigure` option caused the problem. The manual says it best, emphasis mine:

> This option is required if, **and only if**, the `tocloft` and `subfigure` packages are being used together. The two packages can be specified in any order.
>
> -- *(From Section 2.1 of the tocloft manual)*

Since I'm not using the `subfigure` package, removing the option got rid of the errors.